# ESLint consistent-return error with Promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, eslint

I'm getting a [`consistent-return` ESLint error](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return) on the first line of the following code.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  if (condition) {
    asyncMethod.then(data => {
      return resolve(syncMethod());
    }, err => reject(err));
  } else {
    return resolve(syncMethod());
  }
});
```

What is the the missing case where the return is not consistent and how should it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESlint doesn't catch this, but you should [avoid the `Promise` constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)  altogether!

```
return (condition ? asyncMethod : Promise.resolve()).then(data => syncMethod());
```

> What is the the missing case where the return is not consistent?

You weren't `return`ing anything from the `if` block in the promise constructor. Or rather, you shouldn't have `return`ed the result of the `resolve()` call in the `else` block.

Answer (score 2):

You do not return a value from within this `if` block:

```
if (condition) {
  asyncMethod.then(data => {
    return resolve(syncMethod());
  }, err => reject(err));
}
```

This means that the function will return `undefined` if `condition` is true, but return the result of the resolve function, if false.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, can you suggest on how to fix it?

Comment: For sure, just add a return value, that does depend on what you're using this for but it will probably work to just `return asyncMethod.then(data => { return resolve(syncMethod()); }, err => reject(err));`